# Login screen language ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login, screen, language-support

I updated Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04 and now I can't login because I used danish letters (æøå) in my password in 14.04.
 After the update was finished the language changed to Swedish who don't use the same letters.
 I tried to change language in the login screen but when i try it disappears right away.
I'm so sad now because I had so many things in the hard drive.
 Hope anyone have a solution because I tried everything possible i could find here and other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a big problem. The Danish and Swedish layouts are quite similar.

- å is available on the same key as with the Danish layout
- To type æ, press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Ø</kbd>
- To type ø, press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Æ</kbd>

HTH

*Edit:*

For the case you use the English (US) layout, you can try to use [code points](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#ctrlshiftu) instead.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> followed by 00e5 followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> => å

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> followed by 00e6 followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> => æ

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> followed by 00f8 followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> => ø

Comment: Hi Gunnar. I tried AltGr + (æøå) but it type (';]) instead. Num keys doesn't work either I can't turn it on even I use the "num lock key".

Comment: @TinaAndersen: Sounds like you have the English (US) layout then, not the Swedish one. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Now i will only use letter from English in my password....

Comment: @TinaAndersen: Great! Then can you please click the gray checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it and to show other visitors that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you, so here goes:

On my ubuntu 18.04 machine, when I switch it on and don't touch any keys it goes straight to the login page waiting for typed input but I can also log in from any machine on my local network.

From my old Windows machine using putty I can log in via ssh on port  22. I think ubuntu runs ssh server by default, so you should be able to get to your ubuntu machine. From my Windows machine I can just run "putty" and fill in the local IP address, or from a DOS box, type "**putty -ssh myuser@192.168.0.12 -pw mypassword**" ( For obvious reasons that is not my real username or password)

The problem for you is to get those Danish letters to replace 'mypassword'.  [This link](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Denmark:_Typing_%C3%86,_%C3%98,_and_%C3%85#Type_the_.C3.86.2C_.C3.98.2C_.C3.85_and_.C3.9F_using_the_10_key_pad_and_the_Alt_key.) enabled me to do a ø for example, using a UK keyboard. Note that you must use the numeric keypad for the numbers, not the main keyboard.

Once you're logged in then the normal command line command **passwd** should let you change your password. It might be a good idea to have a password that uses just letters and numbers that are common to all nations' keyboards, until you are comfortable with making changes.

Comment: Hi Nick. I'm looking at it right now and downloaded PuTTY on an old laptop with Windows 10 on wireless. The linux computer is connected by lan-wire to same router. Opened it and make it run. Typed in IP adress "192.xxx.xxx.x in "Host Name (or IP adress)" Port "22" Connection type: SSH. And then pressed Open. It said Network error. Connection refused. Then i found something else and tried that too. Connection type: Serial > COM1 to 4. Only COM3 came up with a blank black screen with a green thing. I can write my password (pw) but nothing happens when i press enter

Comment: Hi, it appears that the ssh server is not loaded by default with ubuntu. I don't remember installing it but I must have done so. Without it, there is no way that you can login from another machine; 'connection refused' is what I would expect if there is no ssh server on your machine. The only thing I could suggest would be to login from a terminal window on the offending ubuntu machine - you can do that with CTRL ALT F1. At least that would free you from any display glitches from the GUI but you won't be able to see the password as you type.

Comment: Ah, I see that you have solved the problem with Gunnar's help, I'm glad.

Comment: Thx for the help anyway :-)